# QThread: What should be the parent of a PyQt signal?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, signals-slots

I have a PyQt GUI application with a main window and several workers of different types. I want to display notifications from the workers in the main window, something like:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    messageToDisplaySignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    ...

    def displayStatus(self, s):
            self.infoLabel.setText(s)

class Worker1(QThread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        self.parent.messageToDisplaySignal.emit('Worker1 started')
        ...
```

I saw recommendations to send only signals created by the object itself, but this is violated here. If I create `messageToDisplaySignal` in `Worker1`, I will also need to implement similar signals in all worker classes and to subscribe to them all in `MainWindow`. Is there a more proper way to go?

What is the exact reason of these recommendations (to send only signals created by the object itself) is another interesting question. What exactly will be bad otherwise?

Comment: I don't know why it's recommend, but what you could do is create just 1 `QThread` with the signal and accompanying logic, and subclass it for as many workers as you need.  Then connect main window to the superclass and all the subclasses should propagate the signal to the the superclass.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that matters is *which specific thread* the slot is called in. Qt does not support GUI-related operations of any kind outside the main thread, so it's not merely matter of "recommendations". Your `displayStatus` slot updates a label, which is not guaranteed to be a thread-safe operation. If you want to confirm that it's being called safely, some basic debugging can easily achieve that:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    messageToDisplaySignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.infoLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.infoLabel)
        self.messageToDisplaySignal.connect(self.displayStatus)
        self.worker = Worker1(self)
        self.worker.start()

    def displayStatus(self, s):
        print(f'slot: {int(QThread.currentThreadId())}')
        self.infoLabel.setText(s)

class Worker1(QThread):
    def run(self):
        print(f'worker: {int(QThread.currentThreadId())}')
        self.sleep(2)
        self.parent().messageToDisplaySignal.emit('Worker1 started')

print(f'main: {int(QThread.currentThreadId())}')
app = QApplication(['Test'])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Output:

```
main: 140526289762112
worker: 140526172448320
slot: 140526289762112
```

So the slot is called *in the main thread*, which is what you want to see. The reason why this works is that Qt automatically detects which thread the signal is emitted from *at runtime*. If the sender and receiver are in different threads, the signal will be posted as an event to the event-queue of the receiving thread. When control returns to the receiving thread, the signal-event will be processed, and any connected slots will be called at that time.

Comment: Thanks!

So for each connected slot Qt saves not only address of callback, but also thread it has to be called in? And it has to be called in the same thread as connect? So one signal emit can lead to calling methods in different threads?

Comment: No, as I said in my answer, Qt checks the thread affinity ***at runtime***. It does not save that information anywhere. It only ever looks at which thread the sender and receiver are in *at the point the signal is actually emitted*.

Comment: By receiver you mean object that provided its method to connect? Do you think objects are assigned to threads? So we can create some object and then move ownership of it to another thread?

Comment: The receiver is the object associated with the slot that is connected to the signal (the C++ syntax of [connect()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) makes this more explicit). As stated in the Qt docs, the `QObject` class has both [thread()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread) and a [moveToThread()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) methods. But signals themselves don't save any kind of thread context, because Qt must work that out dynamically at runtime (because the thread affinity of the sender and/or receiver may have changed since the connection).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that! Thanks!

Comment: If I define `messageToDisplaySignal` in the `Worker1` class instead of the `MainWindow` class, and change the attributes at bit (add `worker1` in `self.worker1.messageToDisplaySignal.connect(self.displayStatus)`,  remove `.parent()` in `self.messageToDisplaySignal.emit('Worker1 started')`) I get the same results in terms of thread id. Is it equivalent? **If it is**, I prefer the approach I described because you don't need a lot of signals defined in the main class. It's clearer which worker provides which signal.